# How to use AngularJS 2 without npm and Node.js?

Tags: angular, npm

The current versions of AngularJS 2 references always npm based configurations.

1. Is it possible to manage a project of AngularJS 2 without npm?
2. Is it possible to use AngularJS 2 in production statically without npm/Node.js

I already found answers for examples using the beta versions of AngularJS 2 usiing links like https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.17/angular2-all.umd.min.js. But for the current versions (like 2.1.1) there is no support left. Every examples and documentations point to npm (like https://angular.io/guide/quickstart).

Comment: Any reason for this?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof I want to use it in a Java project and also served by the Java application itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `node_modules` folder in your project, which you get from npm or you could find online somewhere. I have ran projects without npm a few times, rather than using npm and the  `npm start` command you can just run your code with whatever editor you are usings start commands.

Comment: This I also figured out but if you want to develop AngularJS2 together with TypeScript (with I also prefer) the node_modules folder contains a lot of other stuff that is not required in the production environment. This could be suitable if there is a command to only put the production java script stuff in a separate folder etc.

Comment: That is why you use angular cli or npm becase when you transfer your project into production it strips all of the un-used modules from your project and only deploys what is the bare minimum.

Answer (score 3):

I found after a long search this github Repository with a working example for my question 2.: https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-simple-build